Retrieve the storage used in Azure Postgres Flexible Server using Net SDK
I'm using the Net SDK to retrieve information about my deployed Azure Postgres Servers.  I can get the allocated storage using Azure.ResourceManager.PosgreSql.Flexible.PostgresSqlFlexibleServerData but this only gives me StorageSizeInGB and there is no property that corresponds to storage used.  Obviously there is a way because you can see a percentage used in the Azure Portal.  I'll keep looking!
Here's a code snippet
ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName);
    ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
    
    PostgreSqlFlexibleServerCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetPostgreSqlFlexibleServers();
    string resourceName = dbmap.RowKey;
    PostgreSqlFlexibleServerResource result = await collection.GetAsync(resourceName);
    PostgreSqlFlexibleServerData resourceData = result.Data;
    var storageSize = resourceData.StorageSizeInGB;


please the dotnet code you tried in the above question. Please read How to Ask, along with how to create a minimal reproducible example.

The Azure.ResourceManager.PostgreSql.Flexible namespace currently does not have a property for storagepercentage in the .NET SDK.
The Azure portal displays the used storage percentage, and retrieving it directly through the .NET SDK can be done by using Monitor Metrics since cpu_percent, memory_percent, and storage_percent are part of Monitoring and Metrics for Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server.
Azure Monitor Metrics:
Azure Monitor provides metrics for various Azure resources, including Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server. You can use the Azure Monitor .NET SDK to retrieve metrics related to storage usage. These metrics might not directly provide "used storage" but can offer insights like "storage consumed."
To achieve this, we need to configure diagnostic settings to access logs, which allows for effective monitoring of the Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server instance.



logs:
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL"
| where MetricName == "cpu_percent"
| limit 10



For the above image, logging data related to PostgreSQL sessions is not being sent to the specified Log Analytics workspace. Configuring this logging and data transmission is crucial for monitoring and analyzing PostgreSQL session activities, including wait statistics and database name identification.
The only option left is configuring diagnostic settings and accessing logs in Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server.
Steps:

Create a Log Analytics workspace
Navigate to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server instance, and in the navigation menu, under Monitoring, select Diagnostic settings.
Click on the "Add diagnostic setting" button and name your diagnostic setting.
Choose your preferred endpoint for log storage (only Log Analytics workspace) and select the log category.
Save your setting.


-The code below connects to the Azure Monitor Query client using the .NET library, taken from DOC.
       var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    
        var metricsClient = new MetricsQueryClient(credential);

  
        string resourceId = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed/resourceGroups/psam/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/sampatgh77";
        string[] metricNames = new[] { "cpu_percent", "memory_percent", "storage_percent" };
        var metricsResponse = await metricsClient.QueryResourceAsync(resourceId, metricNames);

     
        foreach (MetricResult metric in metricsResponse.Value.Metrics)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(metric.Name);
            foreach (MetricTimeSeriesElement element in metric.TimeSeries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dimensions: " + string.Join(",", element.Metadata));
                foreach (MetricValue value in element.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Timestamp: {value.TimeStamp.ToUniversalTime()}, AverageValue: {value.Average}");
                }
            }
        }

       
        var logsClient = new LogsQueryClient(credential);

        
        DateTime startTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime endTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow; 

       
        var timeRange = new QueryTimeRange(startTimeUtc, endTimeUtc);

        
        string workspaceId = "2f3e93e1";
        string logsQuery = "AzureDiagnostics | where Category == 'PostgreSQLLogs'";
        var logsResponse = await logsClient.QueryWorkspaceAsync(workspaceId, logsQuery, timeRange);

       
        foreach (var row in logsResponse.Value.Table.Rows)
        {
            
            // Console.WriteLine($"{row["message"]}");
        }
    }



Output:




For more query usage, refer to Monitoring and Metrics for Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

